# Is python super documentation wrong?

Tags: python, documentation, super

[image: Doc]

The python doc says super can be called with the following args.

1. super(type, obj) -> bound super object; requires isinstance(obj, type)
2. super(type, type2) -> bound super object; requires issubclass(type2, type)

So the second argument in super has to be either a class to satisfy (1)
or a metaclass to satisfy (2)

[image: Test]

This code runs eventhough self is neither a class nor a metaclass. So is this a mistake in the doc or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: `type` requires a python class; `obj` is an instance of that python class, not the class itself. `self` is used in object-oriented programming when an object refers to itself. So, an instance of class `B` will call `super` on itself by passing its class, `B`,  and itself, `self`. The example is correct.

Comment: ah ok, now I see. I thought type was referring to the type class not to the argument type. The doc is a little bit confusing, haha, but now it makes sense.

Comment: Learning to read code documentation is a skill unto itself. And each language is different too....